# Capacitive sensor switch

Tags: c++, switch

I am trying to get relays to switch on or off based on if I touch a capacitive sensor, basically a light switch. For some reason, I get two readings that are high capacitive readings when I do a printout. I am not really sure why this is happening. I tried delays in case it was reading my touch too fast but with no luck.

The hardware is basically a 1M resistor between send and receive.

```
// capactitive sensing
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>
CapacitiveSensor   cs_7_6 = CapacitiveSensor(7,6);
// 10 megohm resistor between pins 4 & 2, pin 2 is sensor pin, add wire, foil
const int numReadings = 5;
int index = 0;                  // the index of the current reading
int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int total = 0;                  // the running total
int average = 0;
int relay = A2;
int relay2 = A3;
int relay3 = A4;
int relay4 = A5;
boolean lightState = false;
// sound sample
const int sampleWindow = 50; // Sample window width in mS (50 mS = 20Hz)
unsigned int sample;
//other
boolean isRelaysOn = false;

// capacitive sensor
void setup() {
  cs_7_6.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  // turn off autocalibrate on channel 1 - just as an example
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++)
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  // other
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relay4, OUTPUT);
  turnRelayOff();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

boolean state = false;
boolean lastState = true;
boolean lightTurnedItOff = false;

void loop() {
  Serial.println(capReading());
  if(capReading() >= 3000) {
    Serial.println("threadhold reached");
    lightState = !lightState;
    controlRelay();
  }
}

boolean isOn = false;

void controlRelay() {
  if(lightState == true && isOn == false) {
    turnRelayOn();
    //delay(1000);
  }
  if(lightState == false) {
    turnRelayOff();
    // delay(1000);
  }
}

void turnRelayOn() {
  int delayAmount = 100;
  digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
  delay(delayAmount);
  digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
  delay(delayAmount);
  digitalWrite(relay3, LOW);
  delay(delayAmount);
  digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
  delay(delayAmount);
  digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
  delay(delayAmount);
  digitalWrite(relay4, LOW);
  isOn =true;
}

void turnRelayOff() {
  digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(relay3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(relay4, HIGH);
  isOn = false;
}

int capReading () {
  // get average.
  total= total - readings[index];
  readings[index] =  cs_7_6.capacitiveSensor(30);
  total= total + readings[index];
  index++;
  if (index >= numReadings)
    index = 0;
  average = total / numReadings;
  delay(100);
  return average;
}
```

The output doesn't make much sense sometimes either, here are a few samples:

> 11 16 21 22 32 61 74 threadhold reached 6191 threadhold reached 6167
>   threadhold reached 30 15 11 12
>
> 6 10 17 44 2144 3745 threadhold reached
>   -475 threadhold reached
>   -3129 22 10 12 13
>
> 15 13 7 20 23 725 2726 2735
>   -6373
>   -3197 threadhold reached 4127 2714 54 40 43 34 24 27 31

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
readings[index] =  cs_7_6.capacitiveSensor(30);
```

...you are assigning an "int" the value from a method of type "long".

Likely you will want to change all your types used to track the capacitance value, including the type of your "capReading" method, to "long".

Comment: oh, look at that. Didn't even realize that library returned a long. Looking at examples for library shows it definitely does. Will try this fix.